# mask-rcnn can not correctly mask "long-thin" objects, like animal tail

Tags: python, tensorflow, mask, object-detection-api

I tried mask-rcnn from tensorflow object detection api to segment human sperm with long tails. The model *mask_rcnn_inception_v2_coco* works well with masks only on head (both bounding box and mask). But when I added tail masks in training annotation, using the same config file, the bounding box works still (successfully detects the whole sperm with tail), but the masks are not detected correctly, not even for the head. The inference result images are shown below for reference.
[image: annotation mask with tail][image: annotation mask without tail]

As you may see, when I added tail mask in annotation, the bbox showed correctly, but the mask not. Even the head was not marked correctly. So it seems that the model gets "confused" somehow when I added tail mask in annotation.

I also tried to add the 0.25 and 4 to the aspect_ratio array parameter in .config file as follows for tail mask training, but that did not help:

```
  grid_anchor_generator {
    scales: [0.5, 1.0, 2.0]
    aspect_ratios: [0.25, 0.5, 1.0, 2.0, 4.0]
    height_stride: 16
    width_stride: 16
  }
```

Could anybody give a clue on the reason for this?